# How to test that action uses argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

I am supposed to be using test-driven development but in this particular case, as I am having trouble, I implemented the action method first. It looks like this:

```
public ViewResult Index(int pageNumber = 1)
{
    var posts = repository.All();
    var model = new PagedList<Post>(posts, pageNumber, PageSize);

    return View(model);
}
```

Both the repository and the `PagedList<>` have been tested already. Now I want to *verify* that when the action is given a page number that the page number is actually considered.

```
private Mock<IPostsRepository> repository;
private HomeController controller;

[Test]
public void Index_Doohickey()
{
    var actual = controller.Index(2);

    // .. How do I test that the controller actually uses the page number here?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using this pagedlist nuget? https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/
The component has a method to get some meta data which then has a property for the current page number.

https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/PagedListMetaData.cs

What you might have to do in your test is to inspect the model within the View (your actual variable). 
Cast `actual` to `ViewResult` to get your model.

e.g.

```
ViewResult actual = controller.Index(2) as ViewResult;

// not 100% sure about the code below, I didn't tried it out
var list = actual.Model as PagedList<Post>;
var pgNumber = list.GetMetaData().PageNumber // <- assert this
```

You also might have to mock the repository to return one ore more elements. Don't know how this viewlist thing behaves if the list is empty...

Comment: I am not using that library actually. I understand your answer though and will see if I can get something working based on how that library does things. Thanks.